# IIS 7.5 hosting mvc 3 razor app default page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, razor, iis-7.5

I have a MVC 3 Razor app and I need to deploy it on `http://www.mydomain.com`.

The trouble is that that, when I hit `http://www.mydomain.com` it gives a `404 Error`. I need `http://www.mydomain.com/Home` view loaded by default, I would like to avoid using a redirect method as it is not SEO friendly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for the default setting, you can use the `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` method that is available in `Global.asax.cs` to mark the default controller and its corresponding action method. Regarding hitting www.mydomain.com and getting a 404 error, I need more information. if you are on windows and working on a developer machine, did you add the entry to hosts file located in

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc

Comment: Thanks, I was missing a default route in global.asax.cs, you pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't chanegd the RegisterRoutes in the Global.asax.cs file, then it defaults to /Home/Index
see below.

```
routes.MapRoute(
 "Default", // Route name
 "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
 new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
 );
```

So the 4th line of code is where the defaults are configured.